# What role does an API serve in MVC?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I'm still trying to understand MVC to it's fullest.

I know that in a normal setup, the user requests a webpage. That request gets read by the controller and if for example the user needs to see 5 blogposts, it asks the Model to retrieve 5 blogposts out of the database and give those back to the controller. The controller then sends those 5 blogposts to the View, where they get inserted into a normal webpage. The View then returns the data to the user and they see 5 blogposts on the website. (Please correct me if I am wrong. I find it really hard to grasp, for some reason.)

Now I am using React in a project and I would like to do API calls to my PHP to retrieve data.

Does this mean that if I request "website.com/api/blogposts/5", the Controller in PHP reads that it's an api call, asks the Model for 5 blogposts and sends this data back as a response. This would make React the View, right?

Sorry if this is supposed to be basic information. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: React is its own app. The API is its own app, and the view is just the JSON rendering of the data.

Comment: JavaScript can be part of the view if the backend builds the webpage and it is enhanced with dynamic JavaScript. But in the case of a React single-page app requesting data through an API, we're not talking about MVC anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you might be conflating a few concepts so let's take a second to separate them.

Let's talk about web API's first, based on the context you've given you're trying to build a react app that communicates with a PHP API. MVC doesn't necessarily apply here. It exists as a separate application so trying to think of them together in some kind of MVC architecture is going to cause confusion. This API could feature an architecture like REST and would be built to serve data to your client-sided application.

React, my knowledge of the platform isn't extensive however in theory you could map out some type of MVC style architecture in how you structure your project, but React isn't an MVC framework. It's very component based and designed to create reusable components for single page applications. You can read more about this [here.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html)

MVC, I find it easiest to explain using asp.net mvc as an example but I'll try to explain a way that doesn't depend on that. MVC is a principle seen most in the typical server-sided web page loading platform. The view being the web page, the controller being a route on a server, and the model defining the data seen on the page which was returned by the server. Most of your MVC guides will explain this pretty thoroughly.

To summarize, if you're trying to learn React for your front-end applications and design an API in PHP to use with it, you'll want to learn React how it was designed to be used. For the API, take a look at good REST practices and just general PHP API designs. If you want to learn MVC, checkout an MVC framework that is built on top of that principle. The concept has some age to it now, so some of the newer technologies like React don't really use the same principles.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that if I request "website.com/api/blogposts/5", the Controller in PHP reads that it's an api call, asks the Model for 5 blogposts and sends this data back as a response. This would make React the View, right?

This could be an approach. However, since i've done this before **I strongly recomend not to put the API logic inside the controllers**. If your application tends to scale, your controller will become huge, and that is something you want to avoid.

What you should probably do is to create a restful implementation that handles the requests and validations, and from there you can call your controllers to retrieve the processed data and then answer the request. **With this approach you will get more maintanable and consistent code.**
And of course, you will keep your MVC pattern implementation clean and pure.